# Como substituir um caractere especial em lua?

Tags: lua

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo da forca, mas encontrei um problema, não consigo substituir o caractere **ã**.

Segue o código:

```
local done = false
local words = {
    "bola", "casa", "avião"
}


local randomWord = words[math.random(#words)]

while not done do
    print(randomWord)
    print(string.gsub(randomWord, "%a", "_"))
    done = true
end
```

Resultado: ---ã-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua usa o `isalpha` do C para fazer o pattern matching da expressão `%a`, por definição ele só aceitará caracteres entre '**a**' e '**z**' e '**A**' e '**Z**', logo não pegará o '**ã**' como um. No seu caso um simples `.` resolverá o problema:

```
print(string.gsub(randomWord, ".", "_"))
```

O `.` em regex serve para pegar qualquer caractere.